# Javascript - best way to generate date such as Jul 27, 2016 4:53:18 PM

Tags: javascript, datetime

What would be the best way to generate a date such as : Jul 27, 2016 4:53:18 PM in javascript ?

I thought about concatenating a string but I am having trouble finding how to get the month in the particular abbreviated format (Jul).

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Have you tried the built-in `Date` object?

Comment: I think concatenation is the best way to go here!

Comment: @gcampbell : Yes, but there seem to a getMonth() method, which returns the month as an int (i.e: 1 for february), but I am looking for an abbreviated month such as Jul, and I am not sure how to get that

Comment: Javascript doesn't have that, but you can just make a simple array consisting of months, as in `["Jan", "Feb", ...etc]` and use the `getMonth()` method to get it by doing `array[date.getMonth()]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For browsers supporting `Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`:

```js
var month = [];

for(var n = 0; n < 12; n++) {
  month[n] = (new Date(0, n + 1)).toLocaleString("en", {month: "short"});
}

console.log(month);
```

Or with `Intl.DateTimeFormat()`:

```js
var month = [],
    intl = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", {month: "short"});

for(n = 0; n < 12; n++) {
  month[n] = intl.format(new Date(0, n + 1));
}

console.log(month);
```

Note: `new Date(0, n + 1)` is generating a date in the year 1900, which is OK since we only care about the month here.

Finally, this should be pretty close to your final expected output:

```js
var intl = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
  "en-US",
  {
    month  : "short",
    day    : "numeric",
    year   : "numeric",
    hour   : "numeric",
    minute : "numeric",
    second : "numeric"
  }
);

console.log(intl.format(Date.now()));
```

Comment: @ Arnauld : Thanks ! I didn't know you could do that :) That's great.

Answer (score 0):

To get the abbreviated month you can use the following code snippet:

```
var monthShortNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
];

function monthShortFormat(d){
  var t = new Date(d);
  return t.getDate()+' '+monthShortNames[t.getMonth()]+', '+t.getFullYear();
}
```